# how to find distinct values in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have the following in my console:

```
@user.favcolors
=> [#<FavColors id: 1, color_id: 18, fav_id: 1>,
    #<FavColors id: 2, color_id: 19, fav_id: 1>]
@user.favcolors.count
=> 2
```

However, since fav_id is same in both results (1).  I want this count to be 1, instead of 2.

Is there a way I can put `where` clause in the code `@user.favcolors`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@user.favcolors.find(:all, :group => 'favcolours.fav_id')
```

Comment: `@user.favcolors.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT favcolors.fav_id').count` worked for me.  thanks for telling me that find can be called on the association.